# Eclipse XML editor in RCP Application Not working

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rich-text-editor

I am trying use Eclipse Default XML editor in my RCP application. I got this code from

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_something_that_is_not_a_file%3F

So I created StringStorage and StringInput just like provided in the link.

Running on 
Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers

Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Build id: 20190614-1200

jdk1.8.0_121

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IStorage;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath;

public class StringStorage implements IStorage{

    private String string;

      StringStorage(String input) {
        this.string = input;
      }

      public InputStream getContents() throws CoreException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());
      }

      public IPath getFullPath() {
        return null;
      }

      public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
        return null;
      }

      public String getName() {

        return string;
      }

      public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return true;
      }
}
```

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IStorage;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPersistableElement;
import org.eclipse.ui.IStorageEditorInput;

public class StringInput implements IStorageEditorInput {
    private IStorage storage;
    StringInput(IStorage storage) {this.storage = storage;}
    public boolean exists() {return true;}
    public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {return null;}
    public String getName() {
       return storage.getName();
    }
    public IPersistableElement getPersistable() {return null;}
    public IStorage getStorage() {
       return storage;
    }
    public String getToolTipText() {
       return "String-based file: " + storage.getName();
    }
    public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
      return null;
    }
 }
```

Now instead of calling editor ID "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor" in the link. I want to call custom editor I created in plugin.xml extentions.

Because I want to give control to the class who extends XMLMultiPageEditorPart so I get "design" and "source" tab kind of XML editor in my application to show SCXML files (State Chart XML)

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IStorage storage = new StringStorage((String)o);
IStorageEditorInput input = new StringInput(storage);
page.openEditor(input, "org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart");
```

This is my class extending XMLMultiPageEditorPart

```
import org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart;

public class MyXMLEditor  extends XMLMultiPageEditorPart {



}
```

Now I will show you part of plugin.xml

```
<editor

            contributorClass="org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorActionBarContributor"
            default="true"
            id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart"
            name="XML_Editor.name"
            symbolicFontName="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.textfont">
            <class class="org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart">
                <parameter name="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.unsupported_preferred_default" value="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xmlsource"/>
            </class>

            <contentTypeBinding
                contentTypeId="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml" />
            <contentTypeBinding
                contentTypeId="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xmlsource" />
      </editor>
```

For secondcontentType I am getting this yellow warning >> Referenced identifier 'org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xmlsource' in attribute 'contentTypeId' cannot be found

Finally this is Manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: V2
Bundle-SymbolicName: generic.layer.editor.v2;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 ./lib/apache-commons-lang.jar,
 ./lib/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar,
 ./lib/org-apache-commons-logging.jar,
 ./lib/org.apache.commons.collections.jar,
 ./lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar,
 ./lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar,
 ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar,
 ./lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15-sources.jar,
 ./lib/jdom-2.0.5-contrib.jar,
 ./lib/jdom-2.0.5-sources.jar,
 ./lib/jdom-2.0.5.jar,
 ./lib/mockito-core-2.13.0.jar,
 ./lib/dtd-xercesImpl.jar,
 lib/spring/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/spring/spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,
 lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar,
 lib/gson-2.8.2.jar,
 lib/javax.json-api.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_1.6.0.v201905291408.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_1.2.100.v201901310548.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui_1.2.300.v201904272112.jar
Bundle-Activator: generic.layer.editor.v2.Activator
Import-Package:  javax.xml.stream
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.util,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.jface.text.information,
 org.eclipse.jface.text.source,
 org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers,
 org.eclipse.ui.navigator,
 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources,
 org.eclipse.ui.part,
 org.eclipse.ui.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline,
 org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.5.100",
 org.eclipse.zest.core,
 org.eclipse.zest.layouts,
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.10.1",
 org.apache.commons.io;bundle-version="2.2.0",
 org.apache.commons.lang;bundle-version="2.6.0",
 org.junit, 
 org.eclipse.compare.core;bundle-version="3.6.100",
 org.eclipse.compare;bundle-version="3.7.101"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Export-Package: 
 generic.layer.editor.v2.services,
 org.apache.commons.collections,
 org.apache.commons.collections.bag,
 org.apache.commons.collections.bidimap,
 org.apache.commons.collections.buffer,
 org.apache.commons.collections.collection,
 org.apache.commons.collections.comparators,
 org.apache.commons.collections.functors,
 org.apache.commons.collections.iterators,
 org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue,
 org.apache.commons.collections.list,
 org.apache.commons.collections.map,
 org.apache.commons.collections.set,
 org.apache.commons.lang,
 org.apache.commons.lang.builder,
 org.apache.commons.lang.enum,
 org.apache.commons.lang.enums,
 org.apache.commons.lang.exception,
 org.apache.commons.lang.math,
 org.apache.commons.lang.mutable,
 org.apache.commons.lang.reflect,
 org.apache.commons.lang.text,
 org.apache.commons.lang.time,
 org.apache.commons.logging,
 org.apache.commons.logging.impl,
 org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,
 org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,
 org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui
Bundle-Vendor: XILO
```

When I tried to load my view with .scxml file and expect Eclipse XML editor to show up. I getting below erron on console.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-09-26 11:21:12.102
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart$PageInitializationData.sendInitializationData(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.createSourcePage(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.createPages(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.SCXMLView$1$1.run(SCXMLView.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at generic.layer.editor.v2.Application.start(Application.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong.  Please let me know if you need more information. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: XMLMultiPageEditorPart is an **internal** class. You are breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by trying to extend it like this.

Comment: @greg-449 I understand the risk here. It is just for internal use.

Comment: @greg-449 are there really good inbuit XML editor ready to use in RCP which shows XML/SCXML in nice way across platforms (windows,linux,Mac) ? Appreciate if you know another right alternative for this task

Comment: Most people just use the WST XML editor (the one your are looking at). If you want to edit a different file type all you have to do is add a file association, not a new editor. If you are trying to edit 'in storage' data without a file the problems is going to be that many editors expect the input to be `IFileEditorInput` or `IURIEditorInput`.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh okay. My file extention is SCXML ( state chart XML) very similar to XML.  How can I add file association for this so that I can use WST XML editor in my application ? Sorry if I am asking too many questions but I need to fix this...

Comment: Look at the `file-assocation` part of the `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes` extension point. Plenty of info in the Eclipse Help.

Answer (score 0):

The class is expecting the initialization data its own editor extension declares: https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.sourceediting/blob/master/xml/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/plugin.xml#L324 (it controls what happens when opening an unsupported file type). You don't actually need to define a new editor, you can just pass in the ID of the existing one.

Comment: you mean I change like this  page.openEditor(input, "org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart"); and remove my MyXMLEditor class and entries from plugin.xml ?

Comment: Unless you really wanted to define an editor of your own, yes. Be sure to clean the configuration space in your launcher while testing so that the hangers are picked up.

Comment: I updated code as you suggested and also added new entries for editor in plugin.xml just like your code but I am getting same error. I updated the question with new changes.  I appreciate your help. Also 1 question, are there really good inbuit XML editor ready to use in RCP which shows XML/SCXML in nice way across platforms (windows,linux,Mac). I mean I am happy to use another XML editor instead of Eclipse XML editor if it shows such files in proper useful format.

Comment: Is your plugin.xml defining its editor with the same ID as the existing XML Editor? It shouldn't.

Comment: the code you shared uses same ID as the existing XML editor so I used same. Any way I changed and gave it a new unique ID but no change in error.

Comment: Did you set the option to clear the configuration space in your Eclipse Application launch configuration?

Comment: Including the stack trace?

Comment: this is what I did  Run> Run Configurations > main> select checkbox "clear"          Under "tracing" tab there is no option for clear.

Comment: I'm directing you to the Configuration tab: https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/launchers/configuration.htm?cp=4_3_3_0_3 You need to have it clear the configuration area whenever you tweak a `plugin.xml` file.

Comment: Oh. I see it as already selected "clear the configuration ...before launching".

Comment: Ah, now I see that you've packed xml.ui into your plug-in, but not xml.core. org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui requires org.eclipse.wst.xml.core, and the latter is where the org.eclipse.wst.xml.xmlsource content type is declared.